# Find the period of $|\sin x| + |\cos x - 1|$

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

I want to find the period of this function , I know that the period of $|\sin x| + |\cos x|$ is $π/2$ but what can a $-1$ do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$|\sin(x)|+|2 \sin^2(x/2)|$$

The first one: $\pi$

The second: $2 \pi$

The total $2 \pi$

Comment: Why the period of |cosx - 1| is 2π?

Comment: |cosx| -> π and |cosx - 1| -> 2π why?

Comment: Because it is equal to $2 sin^2(\frac{x}{2})$

Comment: Oh sorry ! I get it :D thanks

Comment: Also $|\cos x - 1| = 1 - \cos x$ for all $x$. As $\cos x$ has period $2\pi$, so does $1 - \cos x$.

Comment: @SimonS that one is correct too. even Simpler.

Answer (score 0):

$$x\mapsto |\sin(x)|$$
is $\pi-$periodic.

$$x\mapsto |\cos x-1|$$
is $2\pi-$periodic,

therefore the sum is $2\pi-$periodic.

Answer (score 0):

$$|\sin x| + |1 -\cos x|
= \left\{  
 \begin{array}{ll}
  2 \sin(x/2)\sin(x/2 + \pi/4) & \text{ if  $0 \le x \le \pi$} \\
  2 \sin(x/2)\sin(x/2 - \pi/4) & \text{ if  $\pi \le x \le 2\pi$} 
\end{array} \right. \text{ is $2\pi$-peridoic.}$$